# Why isn't the empty string an identity of concatenation?

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading this blog post by Eric Lippert http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/#more-1228 and became aware that the empty string is not an identity of concatenation in C#. I haven't run into a situation that made me aware this was the case and always just assumed it was an identity. I assume there is some good reason why

```
  string NullString = null;
  NullString = NullString + String.Empty; // results in and empty string, not null
```

results in an empty string rather than `null`, what is that reason? Why is there no identity of string concatenation? Was it made that way for convenience or practicality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) explains this behavior:

> An Empty string is used in place of any null argument.

Basically, the `String.Concat` method was designed to exhibit this behavior.

---

> Was it made that way for convenience or practicality?

While only the framework design team could directly answer this, this behavior does has some practical benefits.  This behavior allows you to concatenate strings with `null` and not create `null` results, which reduces the number of explicit `null` checks required in most code.  Without this behavior, `someString + "abc"` would require null checking, wheras with it, a non-null value is guaranteed.

Comment: And why was it designed to exhibit this behaviour, rather than the alternative behaviour of returning the other operand unchanged if one operand is the empty string?

Comment: @delnan That's really something nobody (other than maybe a framework designer) can directly answer.  I'd suspect this was designed this way to reduce the number of null checks required, but that's only a guess, as I wasn't part of the framework design team ;)

Comment: Perhaps it can't be answered reliably, but that **is** the question after all. And it's not the first question like that. Usually those questions can be answered just fine, with answers showing how the status quo is better than the alternative in question.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that i don't understand "the identity of string concatenation". However, the reason why `null + string.Empty` is not `null` but `string.Empty` is:

because it was implemented in this way.

Have a look:

```
public static string Concat(string str0, string str1)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str0))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return str1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
        {
            return str0;
        }
        int length = str0.Length;
        string text = string.FastAllocateString(length + str1.Length);
        string.FillStringChecked(text, 0, str0);
        string.FillStringChecked(text, length, str1);
        return text;
    }
}
```

This is also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx):

> The method concatenates str0 and str1; it does not add any delimiters.
>   **An Empty string is used in place of any null argument**.

If you ask for the *why*. I assume because it's safer this way. If you want to concat two strings and one of both is null, why should `null` be favored instead of `string.Empty`?

Comment: The question essentially is: Why was it designed, documented and implemented this way?

Comment: @delnan: I don't know, i think because it's safer and more desired to get an empty string instead of `null`. Edited my answer.

Comment: The answer to the general question "why was it designed documented and implemented this way?" is usually "because the alternative is worse"

Comment: @TimSchmelter "identity" means returning the input unchanged. It comes from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function

Answer (score 1):

Because it uses a contract, the purpose of which is described at [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx).

From String.Concat:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
```

Note that `NullString + NullString` also returns an empty string.